# Completing my addarray () formula

Tags: c

I apologize for my vagueness in advance-this is my first post and I can really use some help.

The assignment is as follows:

```
/* Write a function named addarray() that returns the sum of the
elements of an array of int values.  Your functions should take two
parameters, the array and the number of elements in the array.  Make
your function work with the following program; */

/* arraysum.c
 * 
 * Synopsis - displays the value returned by the function addarray()
 * with 2 different sets of parameters.
 *
 * Objective - To provide a test program for the addarray() function.
 * Your answers should be 55 and 0.
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int addarray(int [], int, int);

void main() {
    int array1[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int array2[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    printf("The sum of array1 = %d\n", addarray(array1, 0, 10));
    printf("The sum of array2 = %d\n", addarray(array2, 0, 4));
}
```

This is my solution aid:

```
int addarray(int s[], int i, int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += s[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I cant seem to figure out how to get the proper result. Any help would be appreciated.
This is what I have completed so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addarray(int array1[], int num_elements);
void print_array(int array1[], int num_elements);

void main(void)
{
   int array1[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
   int sum;

   printf("\nArray:\n");
   print_array(array1, 10);

   sum = addarray(array1, 10);
   printf("The sum is %d\n .", sum);
}
int addarray(int array1[], int num_elements)
{
   int i, sum=0;
   for (i=0; i<num_elements; i++)
   {
     sum = sum + array1[i];
   }
   return(sum);
}

void print_array(int array1[], int num_elements)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<num_elements; i++)
   {
     printf("%d ", array1[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

I cant figure out how to get a second array to be summed up.
Such as Array2.

Comment: That code isn't even going to compile. You can't use reserved words (e.g., `int`) as variable names. You should be more specific about your question. For example, if you don't understand a particular compiler error, please include that error in the question. Right now this doesn't look like a question, but rather a request to *"please do my homework for me."*

Comment: I posted my completion so far, I can not figure out how to get the second array to be counted.

Comment: You were shown how to do the second array in the assignment description you posted.

Comment: I got the aid necessary, thank you all very much for your help.

Comment: Like @WeatherVane already pointed out, all you have to do is swap your `main` in your implementation with the `main` they provided, and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a reserved word.you can't give a variable the name int.besides,the assignment says the function should take two parameters,not 3.check this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addarray(int arr[],int size);

void main() {
  int array1[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int array2[4] = {0,0,0,0};

  printf("The sum of array1 = %d\n", addarray(array1,10));
  printf("The sum of array2 = %d\n", addarray(array2,4));
}

int addarray(int arr[],int size)
{
    int sum = 0 , n ;
    for( n = 0 ; n < size ; n++ )
    {
        sum += arr[n];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I get an error on line 16:error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode|

Comment: The edit worked, can you explain what you did though. I would love to learn how your edit performs.

Comment: I moved the declaration of the variable n to outside the loop.

Comment: so that way when n is defined in the for loop has a variable to work with, correct?

Comment: Declaring a variable inside a for loop is rejected by your compiler,so i declared it outside.

Comment: @AraMod - Putting your compiler into C99 mode (with the `-std=c99` flag) should also allow you to declare a loop variable within a for loop (as the error suggests).